# Aggregating data from multiple tables of same format in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 5 simple tables, that are all the same format.
Eg:
Table 1:

| Color | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Blue | 1 |
| Red | 2 |

Table 2:

| Color | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Blue | 0 |
| Red | 9 |

Table 3:

| Color | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Blue | 3 |
| Red | 1 |

etc.

What is an efficient SQL query to aggregate the data from all these tables with the same format? Desired output:

| Color | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Blue | 4 |
| Red | 12 |

My current idea is to simply join these tables on "Color", and then sum together the values from each column:

| Color | Table 1 Count | Table 2 Count | Table 3 Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Blue | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| Red | 2 | 9 | 1 |

SELECT Color, (Table 1 Count + Table 2 Count + Table 3 Count) as Count:

| Color | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Blue | 4 |
| Red | 12 |

I know there must be a more efficient way to do this without having to join by color first. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Union works faster:

```
SELECT Color, sum(Count) 
FROM (
SELECT Color, Count FROM Table 1 
UNION ALL
SELECT Color, Count FROM Table 2 
UNION ALL
SELECT Color, Count FROM Table 3 
) t
GROUP BY Color
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).